# Type conversion in java

Tags: java

I have an int array which has hour, minutes and second value stored in the int array as

```
int[] arr = {hour, minute, second};
```

How do I convert it to the `java.util.Date` datatype??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: From where are you getting the year, month, and day?

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways, of course. If we assume you don't use joda-time:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, array[0]);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, array[1]);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, array[2]);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop the array (or) using a[0] etc., and get values and construct calendar object. From calendar get date. Use simple date formatter to format the date into required hh mm ss format.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, a[0]);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, a[1]);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, a[2]);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it to convert to an hour/minute/second **today** (since you don't have day/month/year):

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, arr[0]);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, arr[1]);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, arr[2]);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is going to be that Date imples, well, a *date*.  You need the day-month-year too.

Here's a good tutorial on [Date](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php).